# angularjs error, binding doesn't work with this keyword

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Couldn't get start with angularjs, need help.

My app.js

```
var app = angular.module('cartApp', ['ui.router']);

app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function() {

    var dash = this;
    dash.something = "something";

});
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="cartApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-controller="dashboardCtrl">{{something}}

/body>
</html>
```

I think I messed up but don't know where is it.

Comment: Hi, could you please post the full error, normally with injection errors it will tell you which module it had problems injecting.

Comment: You should correct your `script` tag starting with `<` like `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>`, Also refer `app.js` file on `index.html`

Comment: @GeorgeLee oh it doesn't have error just the `{{something}}` is not printing.

Comment: @PankajParkar that's just a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have all your bindings available inside controller context(`this`), so you should use `controllerAs` pattern to get binding available in `this` on the view. There you will be using controller `alias` inside `ng-controller` directive & you should use `dash` to get controller binding.

```
<body ng-controller="dashboardCtrl as dash">
   {{dash.something}}
</body>
```

> Also make sure you have referred `app.js` on the page.

Answer (score 0):

could you try in controller?

```
 app.controller('dashboardCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.something = "something";

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For future references, I suggest to follow this [great tip](https://johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/).

It's very useful because provide better readability and avoid make these kinds of mistakes.